# select some text from html using notepad++

Tags: notepad++

i have recognized some text pattern from html. i want to extract some text from bellow:

```
function OnerMobilePlayer_getPlaylist() {
    var playlist = eval("(" + '["\/ezfiles\/0\/1000\/plugin\/oner\/radios\/32\/20332\/movie_862b1a03d03ed7e602a66d2c9bbe8585.mp4","\/ezfiles\/0\/1000\/plugin\/oner\/radios\/33\/20333\/movie_710e022071e07af283add78ff1847c55.mp4","\/ezfiles\/0\/1000\/plugin\/oner\/radios\/34\/20334\/movie_6113ff40bd75188e45a3fe6d782553c8.mp4","\/ezfiles\/0\/1000\/plugin\/oner\/radios\/35\/20335\/movie_eddd31fc1b3a3938ef76ed02cadafa71.mp4","\/ezfiles\/0\/1000\/plugin\/oner\/radios\/36\/20336\/movie_cbdd83c530ce906023848366f3ebd2d5.mp4","\/ezfiles\/0\/1000\/plugin\/oner\/radios\/37\/20337\/movie_f7c2da1b186f9731ecc8fdb50928e209.mp4","\/ezfiles\/0\/1000\/plugin\/oner\/radios\/38\/20338\/movie_3c0f2f3da72e990b9755e41a99a4a9cc.mp4"]' + ")");
    return playlist;
```

the result i want to extract is like

```
/32/20332/movie_862b1a03d03ed7e602a66d2c9bbe8585.mp4
/33/20333/movie_710e022071e07af283add78ff1847c55.mp4
...
```

i was wondering if there are efficient ways to extract the desired text from original html code using notepad++.

great thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with several regular expression Find/Replaces :

**Step 1**

Do a regular expression find/replace like this:

- Open Replace Dialog
- **Find What:** `.*\[([^\]]+)\]+.*`
- **Replace With:** `\1`
- Check **regular expression** and **. matches newline**
- Click Replace or Replace All

Now you have the List of files.

**Step 2**

Do a regular expression find/replace like this:

- Open Replace Dialog
- **Find What:** `"?\\/`
- **Replace With:** `/`
- Check **regular expression**
- Click Replace or Replace All

Now we have fixed the path separator and removed the leading quote.

**Step 3**

Do a regular expression find/replace like this:

- Open Replace Dialog
- **Find What:** `",?`
- **Replace With:** `\n` , you might want to use `\r\n` on windows.
- Check **regular expression**
- Click Replace or Replace All

And finally we have removed the trailing quote and replaced the comma with newlines.